# Why my arithmetic approach in a particular % question does not work

Tags: percentages

Note: Since i could not copy the text of the question i had to attach it as images.

I have 1 question in my book as below 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v27Wa.jpg)
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJxRZ.jpg)

The correct answer to this question is 108.7% based on the reasoning explained in the book; it made sense. They have mentioned that If A is the dollar amount in 2007 for Store T, thus in 2008 the dollar amount will be 0.92A. Thus 1/0.92 = 1.0869 = 108.7%

I tried below approach (the answer was wrong) and i wish to understand the gap in my understanding.

% change from 2006-2007 is 17% --> 117%
% change from 2007-2008 is -8% --> 109%
So (117/109)*100 --> 107.339%

Comment: `% change from 2006-2007` Why would that even matter for a question that clearly asks about the change between 2007-2008, only? FWIW the technical error is in this part: `% change from 2007-2008 is -8% --> 109%`. You can't add percentages relative to different bases.

Comment: Oh I see. Such a silly one. I am not sure whether i understood your sentence `about adding percentages relative to different bases`. So is now following correct `% change from 2007-->2008 is 100-8=92%`. So `(100/92)*100 = 108.69` gets me correct answer but is it correct way of doing ? because you mentioned something about adding percentage which i dint understood.

Comment: `something about adding percentage which i dint understood` Point was that the $\,+17\%\,$ was relative to the 2006 base, while the $\,-8\%\,$ percent was relative to the (different) 2017 base. You can't add them like $\,100+17-8=109\,$ because the denominators are different. Think for example at what happens if you had $\,+50\%, -50\%\,$ instead of $\,+17\%, -8\%\,$. `So is now following correct` Yes.

Answer (score 1):

A drop of $8\%$ of $117\%$ from $117\%$ is $-9.36\% = 107.64\%$.

$$\frac{117}{107.64}\cdot 100 = 108.7\%$$